# angular 7: Filtered data not send to the child component

Tags: angular

I am trying to filter out records that dont have investment amount. If you see the JSON structure , I am trying to filter the FundClassDetailsViewModel object. When I run the filter statement below independently on the data object in debug mode, the filtered data can been seen, however all the data is displayed on the client. I am trying to pass the FundClasses object to the child component. I believe there is an issue with the assignment of the filtered data to the FundClasses object.

```
data.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel
                .reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.FundClassDetailsViewModel), [])
                .filter(obj => obj.InvestedAmount !== null);
```

I think what is happening is that it is taking the first assignment and ignoring the second

```
this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
```

Component

```
public getTermsDetails() {
        if (this.ManagerStrategyId != null) {
            this.termsService.getTermsDetails(this.ManagerStrategyId).subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.TermDetails = data;
                this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
                this.FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.FundClassDetailsViewModel = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel
                .reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(next.FundClassDetailsViewModel), [])
                .filter(obj => obj.InvestedAmount !== null);
            });
        }
```

JSON data

```
 {"FundClassViewModel":{"FundDetailsViewModel":[{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":0,"FundId":0,"ShareClass":"Assign Cogency Fund First","LocalCurrency":null,"Name":"Assign Cogency Fund First "}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":100541,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11167,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"},{"Id":250033,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11166,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":11167,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":1},{"Id":11166,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":1}]},{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":1121,"FundId":652,"ShareClass":"Class B","LocalCurrency":"USD","Name":"Class B USD"}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":250028,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":23732600,"InceptionDate":"2019-05-09T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":1121,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250029,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":119307314,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13717,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250030,"Description":"Class B1","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-05-01T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13716,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B1","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250031,"Description":"Class C","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13715,"LegalFundClassName":"Class C","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250032,"Description":"Class D","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13714,"LegalFundClassName":"Class D","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":13713,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":3},{"Id":13717,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":3},{"Id":13716,"Description":"Class B1","ClassType":3},{"Id":13715,"Description":"Class C","ClassType":3},{"Id":13714,"Description":"Class D","ClassType":3}]}],"VehicleTypes":[{"Id":108,"Spf":false,"Name":"Secondaries","SortOrder":null,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":100,"Spf":false,"Name":"Co-Investment (non-SPF)","SortOrder":1,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":1,"Spf":false,"Name":"FX Trade","SortOrder":2,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":3,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed ETF","SortOrder":3,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":4,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed Security","SortOrder":4,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":2,"Spf":false,"Name":"Mutual Fund","SortOrder":5,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":5,"Spf":false,"Name":"Offshore Fund","SortOrder":6,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":6,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":7,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":9,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US Non - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":8,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":8,"Spf":false,"Name":"EnTrustPermal Product","SortOrder":9,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":7,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Standard","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":105,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – 40 Act","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":106,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – UCITS","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":102,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Blocker","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":103,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Co-Investment","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":104,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Special Sit","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":10,"Spf":false,"Name":"Private Equity","SortOrder":11,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":101,"Spf":false,"Name":"Side-Pocket","SortOrder":12,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":11,"Spf":false,"Name":"Special Situation (non-SPF)","SortOrder":13,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":12,"Spf":false,"Name":"Third Party Fund of Funds","SortOrder":14,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":13,"Spf":false,"Name":"UCITS","SortOrder":15,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":14,"Spf":false,"Name":"Other","SortOrder":50,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false}],"ClosureStatuses":[{"Id":110,"Name":"Hard Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":111,"Name":"Open","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":112,"Name":"Soft Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":1,"Name":"Open - to all","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Open - to Permal only","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":2},{"Id":3,"Name":"Closed - hard","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":3},{"Id":104,"Name":"Closed - with wait list","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":4},{"Id":100,"Name":"Closed - but will reopen","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":5},{"Id":21,"Name":"Closed - but replacing redemptions","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":6},{"Id":101,"Name":"Redemptions Gated","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":7},{"Id":102,"Name":"Redemptions Suspended","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":8},{"Id":103,"Name":"In Liquidation","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":9}]},"FundTermsViewModel":null,"LegalFundClassViewModel":null}
```

Comment: So just to clarify, you're trying to get all of the `FundClassDetailsViewModel` objects where the `InvestedAmount` property is not equal to `null` ?

Comment: Yes. That’s right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly did it with different approach. This seems to work. Eventually I am keeping the same structure as of input JSON, but with filtered `FundClassDetailsViewModel`.

```
this.TermDetails = this.data;
this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel.forEach(funDetail=> {
      funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel = funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel
        .reduce((prev, next) => prev = prev.concat(next), [])
        .filter(obj => obj.InvestedAmount !== null);
});
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3dq1x)

Comment: Hi Amit it does filter . I have chechbox when clicked should toggle between filtered and unfiltered list. I gave it a try but couldn’t succeed. Could you show it I’m thus example of yours

Comment: I would suggest you to save two responses filtered and unfiltered in two separate variables once you receive the response from the server. And use them accordingly when you toggle the checkbox. Because filtering everytime will take unnecessary processing time.

Comment: Emit a checkboxChange event to parent from child. And based on checked/unchecked value, bind the filtered/unfiltered responses.

Comment: I had tried similar by declaring two variables for filtered and unfiltered list. Had emitted event in which I was assigning filtered and unfiltered variable but didn’t see the values changing

Comment: Without seeing the code it's difficult to say what's the issue. I would suggest you to create a new question with all the relevant details. Because that seems to be a different issue altogether. Also consider closing this question if your original problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks Amit I shall do that

Comment: Hi Amit, I have created a post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108688/toggling-between-filtered-and-non-filtered-list