# Toggling between filtered and non-filtered list

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pass-by-reference

I am trying to filter out records that don't have investment amount. If you see the JSON structure , I am trying to filter the FundClassDetailsViewModel object. I am sending this data to the child component. I need to provide a toggling feature such that clicking the checkbox  would show filtered list and unchecking the checkbox would contain non-filtered list. I have created an object called OriginalList which is initialized at the time of retrieving the data. I am storing the filtered list in the object called Termdetails. I can see that filter is working fine. I have also created an eventemitter to emit an event from parent to child component called getInvestedDetails. If the checkbox is checked,  I am assigning filtered object called TermDetails otherwise I am assigning OriginalList . For some reason I dont see the Original list containing all the records. Whats wrong with my logic

Parent Component

```
public getInvestedDetails(isInvested: boolean) {
        if (isInvested) {
            this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
        } else {
            this.FundClasses = this.OriginalList.FundClassViewModel;
        }
    }

    public getTermsDetails() {
        if (this.ManagerStrategyId != null) {
            this.termsService.getTermsDetails(this.ManagerStrategyId).subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.TermDetails = data;
                this.OriginalList = data;
                this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
                this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel.forEach(funDetail=> {
                    funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel = funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel
                        .reduce((prev, next) => prev = prev.concat(next), [])
                        .filter(obj => obj.InvestedAmount !== null);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

JSON data

```
 {"FundClassViewModel":{"FundDetailsViewModel":[{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":0,"FundId":0,"ShareClass":"Assign Cogency Fund First","LocalCurrency":null,"Name":"Assign Cogency Fund First "}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":100541,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11167,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"},{"Id":250033,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11166,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":11167,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":1},{"Id":11166,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":1}]},{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":1121,"FundId":652,"ShareClass":"Class B","LocalCurrency":"USD","Name":"Class B USD"}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":250028,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":23732600,"InceptionDate":"2019-05-09T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":1121,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250029,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":119307314,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13717,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250030,"Description":"Class B1","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-05-01T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13716,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B1","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250031,"Description":"Class C","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13715,"LegalFundClassName":"Class C","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250032,"Description":"Class D","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13714,"LegalFundClassName":"Class D","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":13713,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":3},{"Id":13717,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":3},{"Id":13716,"Description":"Class B1","ClassType":3},{"Id":13715,"Description":"Class C","ClassType":3},{"Id":13714,"Description":"Class D","ClassType":3}]}],"VehicleTypes":[{"Id":108,"Spf":false,"Name":"Secondaries","SortOrder":null,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":100,"Spf":false,"Name":"Co-Investment (non-SPF)","SortOrder":1,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":1,"Spf":false,"Name":"FX Trade","SortOrder":2,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":3,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed ETF","SortOrder":3,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":4,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed Security","SortOrder":4,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":2,"Spf":false,"Name":"Mutual Fund","SortOrder":5,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":5,"Spf":false,"Name":"Offshore Fund","SortOrder":6,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":6,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":7,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":9,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US Non - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":8,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":8,"Spf":false,"Name":"EnTrustPermal Product","SortOrder":9,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":7,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Standard","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":105,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – 40 Act","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":106,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – UCITS","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":102,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Blocker","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":103,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Co-Investment","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":104,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Special Sit","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":10,"Spf":false,"Name":"Private Equity","SortOrder":11,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":101,"Spf":false,"Name":"Side-Pocket","SortOrder":12,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":11,"Spf":false,"Name":"Special Situation (non-SPF)","SortOrder":13,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":12,"Spf":false,"Name":"Third Party Fund of Funds","SortOrder":14,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":13,"Spf":false,"Name":"UCITS","SortOrder":15,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":14,"Spf":false,"Name":"Other","SortOrder":50,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false}],"ClosureStatuses":[{"Id":110,"Name":"Hard Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":111,"Name":"Open","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":112,"Name":"Soft Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":1,"Name":"Open - to all","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Open - to Permal only","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":2},{"Id":3,"Name":"Closed - hard","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":3},{"Id":104,"Name":"Closed - with wait list","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":4},{"Id":100,"Name":"Closed - but will reopen","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":5},{"Id":21,"Name":"Closed - but replacing redemptions","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":6},{"Id":101,"Name":"Redemptions Gated","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":7},{"Id":102,"Name":"Redemptions Suspended","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":8},{"Id":103,"Name":"In Liquidation","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":9}]},"FundTermsViewModel":null,"LegalFundClassViewModel":null}
```

Child component

```
 @Output() termDetailsEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

parent component html

```
<mgr-fund-classes (termDetailsEvent)="getInvestedDetails($event)" [FundClasses]="FundClasses"></mgr-fund-classes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** - You need to do a deep copy of `data` to isolate the references of the two objects, `this.TermDetails` and `this.OriginalList`.

Change this

```
this.TermDetails = data;
this.OriginalList = data;
```

to this

```
this.TermDetails = data;
this.OriginalList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data);
```

**Explanations**

In Javascript, Objects are passed by reference, so `this.TermDetails` and `this.OriginalList` points to the same object.

```
this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel.forEach(funDetail=> {
    funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel = funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel
        .reduce((prev, next) => prev = prev.concat(next), [])
        .filter(obj => obj.InvestedAmount !== null);
    });
```

When you mutate one of the nested objects (the `this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel` array in your case) in one of them, the changes are reflected in both objects (the array is filtered in both objects).